# Refreshing background view from modal view

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to update the view controller that is covered with a modal view in my application, I'm using swift. What I have currently is this:

[image: app screenshot 1]

The view on the right is the caller, and the views on the left are the modal views triggered by each button from the first one. They do basic edit, add new operations. These views are modally presented over the main one, and what I want to do is update the table view controllers enbedded in the two containers once I save the data from one of the modals.

I researched the use of one of the viewLoad events, but I'm kinda stuck at the moment. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it in two ways
 1. Delegate
 2. NSNotificationCenter

In your Model class.h file

```
@protocol someProtoColName<NSObject>
-(void)finishedDoingMyStuff;
@end
@interface ModelClass()
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<someProtoColName> delegateObj;
```

Then in your ModelClass.m

```
-(void)someactionHappend{ 
//this is the method where you save your things call the delegate method inside here like this.
[self.delegateObj finishedDoingMyStuff];
}
```

Then in your CallerClass.h

```
#import ModelClass.h
@interface CallerClass:UIViewController<someProtoColName>
```

Inside CallerClass.m `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
ModelClass *model = [[ModelClass alloc]init];
model.delegateObj = self; 
}
//Now declare the delegate method
-(void)finishedDoingMyStuff{
//update your code that this has happend. this will be called when your model class's button action inside which you sent the `self.delegateObj`message is invoked instantaneously.
}
```

2. NSNotificationCenter

CallerClass.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod) name:@"NOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil];

}

-(void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"NOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil];
}
-(void)someMethod{
       //something has happened, do your stuff
}
```

And in each of the Model class (if they are many or one dsnt matter)|
ModelClass.m

```
-(void)someactionHappend{
//this is your action method that you want to do stuff in the model 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATIONNAME" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: and if I want to do it in swift?

Comment: Same mechansm just swift syntax